# Python output in Excel

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

Trying to get the output of the cartesian product in excel using xlsxwriter and arrange them column-wise but have not been successful.

**Intended Result:**

If the first output is (A,B,C,D,E) the output should be displayed in excel in the following manner:

Row 0, Col 0 = A

Row 0, Col 1 = B

Row 0, Col 2 = C

Row 0, Col 3 = D

Row 0, Col 4 = E

then row+=1 and the next set of results are displayed in the same manner.

**Code:**

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H','I']
list3 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
list4 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
list5 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H','I','J','K','L','M']

list = [(p,q,r,s,t) for p in list1 for q in list2 for r in list3 for s in 
        list4 for t in list5]

x = print(list)

import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.workbook('Stat.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
col = 0

for Apple, Boy, Cat, Dog, Eagle in (x):
  worksheet.write (row, col, Apple)
  worksheet.write(row, col + 1, Boy)
  worksheet.write(row, col + 1, Cat)
  worksheet.write(row, col + 1, Dog)
  worksheet.write(row, col + 1, Eagle)
  row += 1
workbook.close()
```

Comment: did you try see what `x` contains? When I run your code it's just a string containing `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001896A293360>` which is evidently quite wrong

Comment: Aren't you missing the `:` in the `for` statement?

Comment: list = [(p,q,r,s,t) for p in list1 for q in list2 for r in list3 for s in list4 for t in list5]

Comment: It looks like you aren't incrementing the `col` value in your `for` loop. They are all (except Apple) writing to the same column as a result. If you defined column inside the `for` loop and had an col+=1 in between all of those writes it would put them in different columns. You could also just hardcode the column numbers.

Comment: Tried with the changes and now it says TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. E1102:xlsxwriter.workbook is not callable. Am I missing something?

Comment: Assuming that first result of the output is (A,B,C,D,E), I want A to be in Row 0 Col 1, B to be in Row 0 Col 2, C to be in Row 0 Col 3, D to be in Row 0 Col 4, E to be in Row 0 Col 5 and the next set of results to begin in the same manner but in Row 2.

Comment: Why are you doing this `x = print(list)`? Shouldn't you just be looping like this `for Apple, Boy, Cat, Dog, Eagle in (list):`

Comment: also you are just repeating `col + 1` on each line but don't you want `col + 2` `col + 3` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H','I']
list3 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
list4 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
list5 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H','I','J','K','L','M']

# You probably could use product from itertools for this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product
list_combined = [(p,q,r,s,t) for p in list1 
                             for q in list2 
                             for r in list3 
                             for s in list4 
                             for t in list5]

import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Stat.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for row, group in enumerate(list_combined):
    for col in range(5):
        worksheet.write (row, col, group[col])
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Tried running it but it says E1102:xlsxwriter.workbook is not callable.

Comment: Looking at the docs, it should be workbook with a capital W. Try my edit

Comment: That was amazing. Thank You so much. :)

Comment: Hey @Dan can you look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898765/python-combination-with-criteria-and-output-in-excel?noredirect=1#comment90750831_51898765